# how do i fix this function with dictionary to add and print added people?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

currently im trying to solve a problem in the code i wrote, for some reason whenever i call imprimir() it only shows the last added person while it should show all the persons added.

```
libro = {}


def agregar(rut, nombre, edad):

    estudiante = {}

    estudiante['rut'] = rut
    estudiante['nombre'] = nombre
    estudiante['edad'] = edad

    libro['rut'] = estudiante


def imprimir():
    for rut in libro:
        estudiante = libro[rut]
        print(estudiante['rut'], estudiante['nombre'], estudiante['edad'])


def main():
    contador = 0
    while contador < 2:
        rut = input("rut: ")
        nombre = input("nombre: ")
        edad = input("Edad: ")
        contador = contador + 1
        agregar(rut, nombre, edad)
    imprimir()

main()
```

I had the code limited to only 2 people to be added. so if for the first person i write, rut = 1, nombre = 1 and edad = 1, and for the second, rut = 2, nombre = 2 and edad = 2. While using main(), it should print:
1 1 1
2 2 2
but instead it just prints 2 2 2 with 1 1 1 not found, my guess is that somehow the added person are not added but instead rewritten, but i cant find why, if i includo imprimir() inside the while in the main() it prints each person as soon as i finish adding one, but the idea its that the program should print all the added people once i finish adding them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your adding the items with the same key so the `dict` just overrides the last value with each entry you add...

```
libro = {}


def agregar(rut, nombre, edad):

    estudiante = {}

    estudiante['rut'] = rut
    estudiante['nombre'] = nombre
    estudiante['edad'] = edad

    # this would override the previous entry since it's always the same key
    libro['rut'] = estudiante
    # use a key that is unique and all entries will be preserved
    libro[rut] = estudiante
    # or for some truly unique keys
    libro[str(uuid.uuid4())] = estudiante
```

Comment: Bug is in this line
`libro['rut'] = estudiante`

change it to 
`libro[rut] = estudiante`